# Which dlls from the numerous iText 7.2.1.0 dlls

Tags: c#, itext

I have a silly question.
What iText dlls are needed in production?
The Release folder contains a lots of dll (from itext.barcodes to itext.svg) but the program uses only  iText.Kernel.Pdf and iText.Signatures.
:)

Comment: Based on the Java dependencies you will always need kernel, io, commons, and layout. For signing you'll additionally need sign, forms, and probably pdfa.

Comment: Thank you, I put all the dlls so I do not have any problems with it. :)